# Why is the option to add a location to a Blogger post intermittently missing?

Tags: blogger

[image]

You can add locations related to a post on Blogger.com: A widget lets you search Google maps for a geographic place to associate with your post. I just did it a few minutes ago.

However, the option to add a location is not always there, even on posts that have a location associated with them.

**Why is the location option missing when drafting a Blogger post, and how do I ensure it's there?**

I have tried:

- using both [Blogger in draft](http://draft.blogger.com/home) and the [regular dashboard](http://www.blogger.com/home).
- different browsers like Chrome, Opera, and IE.

The [blog](http://www.leftium.com) I am trying to add locations to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option is still in Blogger-in-Draft (blue-logo blogger in the picture you've quoted), it hasn't been released to production Blogger as yet.

Tools that are in BID sometimes get withdrawn and then re-instated, as part of the process of pre-production testing.   That's just one of the disadvantages of using BID.

Comment: Yes, the location option reappeared after a while.